# How to get rid of error in Xampp while opening phpmyadmin

Tags: php, phpmyadmin, xampp

I am using Xampp that has phpmyadmin. When I try to open phpmyadmin I get this error:

`mysqli::real_connect(): (HY000/1045): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)`

In my config file the password is "" so nothing basically.

I have added the screenshot as well for the error. How can I fix it? I tried all the other answer of SO but nothing worked for me. [image]

Comment: Are you able to connect to MySQL by console with root and password empty?

Comment: @jtorrescr I am not sure how to connect by using console. Could you please tell?

Comment: Open a cmd window and enter the command: mysql -u root -p

Comment: I did that with empty password and it says `ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)`

Comment: I dont know, but i suspect the old behaviour is that password is empty for root with xampp, but after version 5.7 of mysql its secure by default so a password is set on installation. In that case, you can search mysqld.log for temporary password to find it

Comment: Could you please tell me where that file is located?

Comment: There is config.inc.php and the password is set to nothing there

Comment: The "invalid settings" error definitely could mean there's some syntax problem with your configuration file, as well. Could you post your entire `config.inc.php` here, obscuring any sensitive information? However, since you're not able to log in through the command line client you should reset your password. XAMPP apparently includes a tool to do this called "resetroot", see https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/75002/recovering-mysql-root-password-xampp for further details.

Answer (score 0):

It seems what you are really asking is how to change the root password since you dont know the one that is in place.

The error you get is simply mysql saying, "ya need a password mate"

A quick google leads me to something like this, which seems reasonable https://gist.github.com/susanBuck/39d1a384779f3d596afb19fcad6b598c

Start mysql without the grant tables and change the password. Restart it again, and you should be good to go. I do not have Xampp or Windows, so i cant try it.

The password you are looking for should be written in the mysqld.log from when it was installed. That might save you some trouble changing it. Search the log file for "temporary password"